# Установил FastReport 4.12 - перестала работать трассировка в Delphi-XE. Как исправить?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Установил FastReport 4.12 на Delphi XE (v.15). Вроде по F9 компилируется нормально, но вот трассировка перестала работать. Начинает ругаться на какие-то файлы ("FrxChm.dcu" - в частности), которых даже в пакете FastReport 4.12 нет.
Как это лечится? Покупать 5-ый за 20 000 рублей не вариант.
Может быть как-то 4-ый Full-version есть? И я просто ссылку не знаю.

Comment: Полный текст "ругани" покажите

Comment: И укажите какая именно трассировка работать перестала, вся и везде, или .. ?

Answer (score 1):

Проверь что у тебя и в Library Path и в Browsing Path добавлен путь `Path\to\FastReport 4\LibD15\`

Comment: В Library путь добавлен. в Debug CPU тоже. В Browsing Path добавления пути к FastReport не помогло.
Я же и писал, что файл `frxChm.pas`, который требует Delphi после использования компанента `frxReport1` его просто нет. Ни в пакете (дистрибутиве), не на ПК. Поэтому пути тут вряд ли помогут.